# ASP.net c# help with using firebird to connect to interbsae

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, firebird, interbase

iv just downloaded the latest version of Firebird ADO.NET Data Provider and im trying to create a connection to my interbase database (2009), which is on a server. i have the following code so far

```
String ConnectionString = "User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=\\\\Server50:D:\\database\\Data\\play.ib;Dialect=3; Charset=NONE;Connection lifetime=15;";
FbConnection addDetailsConnection = new FbConnection(ConnectionString);
addDetailsConnection.Open();
```

the issue is when I try this i get the following error

```
Exception Details: FirebirdSql.Data.Common.IscException: Unable to complete network request to host "\\Server50".
```

please can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

[FirebirdClient](http://blog.cincura.net/230835-firebirdclient-and-interbase/) is for Firebird and tested only with Firebird

So using for Interbase may be dangerous

For Interbase, you can use this [drivers](http://www.ibprovider.com/eng/)

Answer (score 0):

try this for a connection string

```
"User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Data Source=Server50;Database=D:\\database\\Data\\play.ib;Dialect=3; Charset=NONE;Connection lifetime=15"
```